# How to add multiple headers on a fly in Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

```
final Header header1 = new Header("MyHeader", "Something");
final Header header2 = new Header("MyHeader1", "Something else");
final Header header3 = new Header("MyHeader2", "Something if else");
Headers headers = new Headers(header1, header2, header3);

given().headers(headers).param("country_code", "IND").when().get("/get").then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();
```

With the above code I am able to add multiple headers in the URL. Issue is that the headers count and value will be fetched from excel sheet and count of the header may vary.

I need to handle this on a fly. Any suggestions how I should approach this ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve it. Here is my code, hope it helps someone.

```
List<Header> headerList = new LinkedList<Header>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {


        Header header11 = new Header("MyHeader"+ i, "Something"+ i);
         headerList.add(header11);

    }

Headers headers = new Headers(headerList);
```